# Rails profiling time taken for each line execution while process request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, profiling

Is there any better way to find time taken for every logic executed while processing HTTP request. We need profiling individually rather than group and give time taken for multiple things. We tried NewRelic, AppSignal to get this data but no luck.

I have added screenshot too, here we could see ActiveRecord took around 1.5seconds and view rendering view (response) took around 300ms. When we sum these two it's around 2seconds but total time taken for the request is 10seconds. We are not able to find where the rest of 8seconds taken. NewRelic saying 90% of time taken from controller action but no breakdown for this. Is there any better tools to get more detailed info?

**Note**: Most of time it's working fine and we have issue in specific time. But we don't have what is causing slowness, to identify this only we are expecting tool to find this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

AppSignal can help you with this, here is an example of an event timeline AppSignal provides when you are looking at the performance of a specific action.

[image]

This is provided out of the box for Rails. There will be some cases where you want to narrow down even further that's where [custom instrumentation](https://docs.appsignal.com/ruby/instrumentation/instrumentation.html) comes in, it helps you find a specific piece of code that is causing performance problems.

You can [reach out to us at AppSignal](https://www.appsignal.com/contact) and I will be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

There may be tooling options that give you a little more information out-of-the-box. But, if you're really trying to identify bottlenecks you may want to take things into your own hands and do some good old-fashioned debugging. Use ruby's built-in `Benchmark` module in your controller actions and log the results. This may help you identify which sections of code are chewing up response times.

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html